# Pandas: enforcing dataframe dtypes in json with lines=True

Tags: python, pandas

I found Pandas type inference a complete pain in the back, but long story short, how do I keep values as strings and not change them when reading JSON with `lines=True`?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['01','02','03'], 'B': [True, False, False], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, dtype=str)
>>> df
    A      B  C
0  01   True  a
1  02  False  b
2  03  False  c
>>> df.to_json(open('1.json', 'w'), orient='records', lines=True)
>>> pd.read_json('1.json', lines=True)
   A      B  C
0  1   True  a
1  2  False  b
2  3  False  c
```

You can see the leading zeros are removed from column `A`.
I'm working in a larger project where there are many columns that I don't care about, but I don't wanna change them like the column `A` above.
How do I do it?

I also don't wanna change `lines=True` because then file becomes all one line and unreadable.

Comment: I used to have the same problem when writing my df to csv, one thing I used to do was to convert them to str type and write to csv. When i read that csv, i make sure to convert back to original type

Comment: No wait, my bad, looks like your input is already a str, if then try converting it to type 'obj'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dtype={"Col_Name": object}` while reading the json

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['01','02','03'], 'B': [True, False, False], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, dtype=str)
df.to_json('1.json', orient='records', lines=True)
print(pd.read_json('1.json', lines=True, dtype={"A": object}))
```

**Output:**

```
    A      B  C
0  01   True  a
1  02  False  b
2  03  False  c
```

Comment: Thank you. Since I don't know the column names, it seems setting `dtype=object` works for all columns

Comment: Please note, that will convert all columns to 'str'. Ex if you have a column of `int` that also will be converted to `str`

Comment: It's better than the other way, but is it possible to make it just not change anything? Ideally, running read_json/to_json would not change the file.